# Write text into zipfile in python

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I have a function which creates a zip archive with a textfile in it.
Is it possible to do this without creating a temporary file?

```
import zipfile
import os

PROJ_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


def create_zip(name, text):
    with open(os.path.join(PROJ_DIR, "_tmp_file_"), "w+") as f: 
        f.write(text)

    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(PROJ_DIR, "%s.zip" % name), "w",
                         zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zf.write(os.path.join(PROJ_DIR, "_tmp_file_"), "/file.txt")
    zf.close()
```

Comment: You can try to use [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) instead of temporary file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `writestr` instead of `write`, an example

```
zf.writestr('/file.txt', text)
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr).